# subdomains for the images ,videos and others assets in the web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, subdomain

what is the benefit from making subdomain for images in my website?
is it regarding faster downloading or server caching . I noticed that all big sites like facebook and others are doing something like that for images , videos.....

Comment: This isn't a programming question - it would be better fit on webmasters.

Comment: Maybe it is, because a programmer of the site must take care the image url and how to serve it from the different domain. Just bu setup you can not make the site work.

Comment: @aristos: The question is about the benefits of doing this,  not how to serve from a different domain - even if it was this was, it's just a different URL - again nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @UpTheCreek still believe that a programer know better the benefits.

Comment: I'm asking this question just to know more about the benefits , well not how to do that . any way it's a nice discussion . but I'm sure that programmer should take care of this more than the web master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common recommendation for high load, high performance websites: Serving images off different servers can improve your overall performance significantly.

Browsers generally only keep 2-5 connections to the same server, so if your webpage has 10 images, the browser will download 2 to 5 of them  simultaneously, while the rest waits. Using different subdomains will "trick" the browser, and it will open additional connections, which reduces the overall page load time.

Using a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for images, stylesheets and other static content, can also take some load of your webserver, which is another benefit.